Create a Linkedin Article not a post
Using the Linkedin api - can create a post but cannot create a longform article ( publish an article) using the api? Am i missing anything?
TRied even creating an article and adding in the original url
payload = {
        "author": "urn:li:organization:15715",
        "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
        "specificContent": {
            "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
                "shareCommentary": {
                    "text": "Check out my latest article on LinkedIn! " +
                            "This is a brief summary with up to 1300 characters."
                },
                "shareMediaCategory": "ARTICLE",
                "media": [
                    {
                        "status": "READY",
                        "description": {
                            "text": "Summary or excerpt of your article."
                        },
                        "originalUrl": original_url,
                        "title": {
                            "text": "Your LinkedIn Article Title"
                        },
                        "thumbnails": [
                            {
                                "resolvedUrl": "https://www.example.com/header-image.jpg"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

THIS CREATED TO POSTS ..

Please consider bringing solid code that is being used to interact with Linkedin's API. Rephrase your post. Even though, it might seem silly, good grammar and spelling and capitalization do matter and weigh a ton when analyzing  questions. Peace out! [Edit]: @Dai did a great job refactoring.

"Check out my latest article on LinkedIn!" - Timeless words absolutely guaranteed to have people in suspense

Thanks for formatting but do you have any answer on how to create an Article and not just share an article?

So asking why cannot create an article (not share article) - i see you can retrieve and delete article but want to create a long form article programtically using the Linkedin API
